# Nginx/Cloudflare Issues

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I'm tinkering around with Nginx and I'm getting stuff to work which is the most fun I've been having recently honestly. Like actually understanding some of this stuff.
However, I do have some issues and some questions I can't seem to find the answer to (probably because I'm not looking up the correct thing).

Before reading I am running the nginx on the main server and then the application I'm reverse proxying on a Raspberry Pi. I am also not using the normal method of running sites-enabled and sites-available, I'm doing this through the **conf.d** directory.

1.
I'm currently using **letsencrypt** which I just got started, and the question I have for this would be, do I need to listen on both 80 and 443? Or can I just listen on 443 now that it's https. ( also have HTTPS forced via **Cloudflare**).

If I need both port **80** and **443**, would I need my domainname.com.conf file to look like this?

```
listen 80;
listen 443;
listen [::]:80;
listen [::]:443;
```

Is this how I should have it or is there an easier way in doing this?

2.
I've also setup a reverse proxy via Nginx it's pretty basic for now as I'm learning it but the problem I'm getting is I've set it up the way I've seen via multiple guides and answered questions on here already. Would this be better if I used the internal IP?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name  plankanban.domainname.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass   https://externalip:8889;
    }
}
```

With this configuration it doesn't seem like it enjoys it as much sadly.

3.

**Edit:** This has been resolved, installing letsencrypt and using the automatic encryption made a new server block lower down and it had two parts, the second part contained the duplicate call to the same port.
Finally I am getting these errors in my logs about the domain, they seem to have started happening after adding letsencrypt ssl.

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domainname.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.domainname.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domainname.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.domainname.com" on [::]:80, ignored
```

Running grep returns this:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/reverse-proxies.conf:    server_name  plankanban.domainname.com;
/etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.com.conf:    server_name  domainname.com www.domainname.com;
/etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.com.conf:    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
/etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.com.conf:    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
/etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.com:    if ($host = domainname.com) {
/etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.com.conf:    server_name  domainname.com www.domainname.com;
```

Would love to figure these out honestly, I'll keep testing until someone replies.

Thanks for reading and helping in advance,
~Blood